# How change min and max zoom scale in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, svg, uiwebview, wkwebview

I use WKWebView to show svg. It's rather big and i need support of scaling it on pinch gesture. WKWebView do it out of the box. But. It has it's own constraints for min and max zoom scale. 
For example:

subscribe to WKWebView's scrollView delegate and implement method

```
optional func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, 
                                 with view: UIView?, 
                              atScale scale: CGFloat)
{
        print(self.wkWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale, self.wkWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale)
        self.wkWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.01
        self.wkWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20.0
}
```

And in next call it will print: 0.25, 5.0. My values of (0.01, 20.0) are absolutely ignored. Is it a way to correct it?

With deprecated UIWebView there was no such problem. (But there was very unpredictable scaling.)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old now but I'm tackling what seems to be a similar problem and thought my solution might help others. I've wrapped the SVG in the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta id="mw-viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Once I've calculated my desired min/max zoom levels I execute some javascript to grab the `"mw-viewport"` meta tag and edit it's `"content"` attribute's `"minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"` values.

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixed a really nasty bug for my app that was present only on 2 specific models of iPad. I'm showing SVG too with an HTML wrapper, the added tag fixed the minimumZoomScale resetting to some weird value ~1.044...